# jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found

Tags: java, web-applications, smb

The following is my piece of code

```
SmbFile catalExp = new SmbFile("smb://<Shared machine name>/Project share/Home/4.  Folders/planning - Design & Exec/sample.txt",
                    new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(LoadProp.getShrdDomain(),"user","paswd"));
```

In this i am getting the error

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:753)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:140)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:103)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:132)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:674)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:644)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:700)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.createNewFile(SmbFile.java:2027)
```

Is this anything to do with the user rights to that particular shared folder or am I doing anything wrong
Please advice

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error message, and it turned out the problem was that my network path was incorrect. You'll want to ensure that the `NtlmPasswordAuthentication` object is configured correctly, that your network path is correct, and that you've set the jcifs.netbios.wins property correctly, as indicated in the first example [on this page](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/).

For example, to load a remote properties file:

```
final NtlmPasswordAuthentication AUTH = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domainname", "username", "password");

Config.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", "10.10.1.1");

Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream(new SmbFile("smb://10.10.1.1:445/rootfolder/path/filename.properties", AUTH));
props.load(in);
```

(You'll need to add try/catch and input stream closing)

A good way to ensure that all of your parameters are correct is to test logging into and locating the file using a smb/cifs client. For example smbclient on linux/unix:

```
smbclient -Uusername -p 139 //10.10.1.1/rootfolder
```

The domain is displayed at the top when you login with smbclient:

```
Domain=[DOMAINNAME]
```

..and you can navigate to your file to make sure you've got the path correct.

Answer (score 1):

After running into this issue for almost 1 day i realize that these exception is meaningless

- I was just giving wrong path of server side location

Below is the peace of groovy code worked for me

```
        String domain = "domain"
        String user = "username"
        String pass = "password"
        String IP = "xx.yy.zz.aa"
        String sharedFolder="//my//path//to//server//";

    String path="smb://$IP"+sharedFolder+"test.txt";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(domain, user, pass );
    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
    SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
    smbfos.write("testing....and writing to a file".getBytes());
    System.out.println("completed ...nice !");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm getting this error also but only on one device, my code that works on Android 4.04 is

```
 String strprog = "STRING CREATED| "; //debug log string
    try {
        strprog += "NTLM| ";
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth =  new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("username:password");
        strprog += "SMB| ";
        SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb://<pcname>/foldername/filename.txt",auth);

        strprog += "EXIST| ";
        String there = String.valueOf(file.exists());

        strprog += "View| ";
        TextView pp;
        pp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        pp.setText(there);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        strprog += "ERROR! ";
        TextView ll;
        ll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        ll.setText(strprog + e.getStackTrace().toString() + "    " +  e.getMessage() + "   " + e.getLocalizedMessage() );
    }
```

The only difference I see is where you have your `NtlmPasswordAuth` compared to mine.
But as I stated for some reason this throws null input `param` on Andriod 2.0 when I dive deeper then smb://host but I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it turned out that I did not see what the share name was that was mapped to my Windows shared drive... So, using Mac OS, I ran:

`smbutil view smb://MYUSERNAME@HOSTNAME`

After I was prompted for my password, I then was displayed a list of share names (that weren't evident when I looked at this stuff using Windows). Once I found my share name, it was as simple as using that when connecting with JCIFS:

`new SmbFile("smb://HOSTNAME/SHARENAME/path/I/was/trying/to/access", auth);`

Comment: #James What do mean by share name? Is that anything like when you configure something as shared you will provide a name in which it has to be shared?

Comment: This worked for me too, and saved me soooo much of a headache! Thanks and +1! @Sundhar - when you run this command it will be obvious to you: you'll get a print out of all the shares (directories) available on the remote server via `smb://`.